# Stop specific transition before occuring

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got quite a rudementary question that I can't really seem to fix myself. I've already looked into similar answers, but none of the implementations seem to be possible implementations for me.

Basically I have an image(png) that moves around in a little box [**(here is the game)**](http://www.student.bth.se/~jobk16/dbwebb-kurser/javascript1/me/kmom03/baddie2/).
The problem I'm facing is that the image should flip if you change the direction the sprite is moving (left-right) and that it should be able to jump.
The transitions work fine separately, but when I try to jump when faced left it turns right in the jump.

I need to remove the baddie-left before jumping, I suppose. But it doesn't seem to work when I've done it...

**Full disclaimer: We are not supposed to use anything but 'normal' js (ie. no jquery).**

Here is the js:

```
switch(key) {
    case 32: //jumping
        if(!baddie.classList.contains('baddie-jumping')){ 
            baddie.classList.add('baddie-jumping');
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                baddie.classList.remove('baddie-jumping');
            }, 350);
        }
        break;
    case 37: //moving left
        if (left_available(left - step)){
            if(!baddie.classList.contains('baddie-left')){
                baddie.classList.add('baddie-left');
            }
            left = left - step;
        } else {
            left = 150;
            top = 130;
        }
        break;
    case 38:
        if (top_available(top - step)){
            top = top - step;
        } else {
            left = 150;
            top = 130;
        }
        break;
    case 39: //moving right
        if (left_available(left + step)){
            if(baddie.classList.contains('baddie-left')){
                baddie.classList.remove('baddie-left');
            }
            left = left + step;
        } else {
            left = 150;
            top = 130;
        }
        break;
    case 40:
        if (top_available(top + step)){
            top = top + step;
        } else {
            left = 150;
            top = 130;
        }
        break;
}
```

And the css:

```
.content {
    /* If #content position is absolute, the #baddie position will be given in reference to it's parent, which is #content
     * Makes it easier to do collision calculations */
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

.baddie{
    /* Baddie's postition must be absolute, otherwise we can't move him by changing top and left */
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;

    /* Change this to your own baddie! */
    background: url("../img/viking.png");
    background-size: 50px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.baddie-left {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.baddie-jumping {
    transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-40px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add .baddie-jumping class, it just overwrite transform property of .baddie-left class. You should add to your css:

```
.baddie-left.baddie-jumping {
    transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-40px) rotateY(180deg);
}
```